# EOF - stdin/stdout - interactively

Tags: c#, linux, bash, unix

Is it possible to print output (stderr, stdout) "interactively" while operating with "<<EOF"?

The program reads from stdin, for example

`while ((line = Console.Readline()) != null) { ... }`

Whenever I start this program like this:
`./program <<EOF`

I get the following back: `>` which is there the input goes. Then everything processed
is first presented when EOF arrives, so for example

```
./program <<EOF
> command1
> command2
> command3
EOF

result1
result2
...
```

What I want to achieve is output from the program on each line - for example a date,
so that it would be something like this:

```
./program <<EOF
> 20210606@14:41.19.143: command1
> Waiting...
> result1 command2
EOF

"Results already presented, nothing to print..."
```

Is this possible, and if so how?

===============================================

Clarification:

Program x has the following code:

```
string instruction;
  while (true) { 
    currentTimestamp stamp = getInternalTimestamp(); 
    while ((instruction = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
      if (instruction.equals("recv") {
        // Write back to the terminal?
        // This (output below) most likely must arrive at the end - i.e., when "EOF" is received
        WriteToConsole(stamp); 
      }
    }
    sleep(1000 ms); 
  }
```

So would it be possible, for each single line, using "<<EOF"
to receive something similar to this:

"> **1234532444** recv"

"> **1234532444** snd"

?

Given that we only send the following:

> recv (or another command to the program)

How can the terminal print back the timestamps, until EOF is received?

Assumption is:

```
./program << EOF
> recv
> snd
EOF

"Time for send was 113241..."
"Time for recv was 1132....."
```

Is it true this assumption is true? I.e., that we cannot possibly
get the timestamps back this way, until EOF?

Answer (score 1):

The [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) is coming from the Bash shell, and is part of the command line used to start the c# program. As such, it needs to be completed before the program even starts.

Example:

```
$ perl -pe 's{(.*)}{\U$1}' <<EOPerlInput
> foo
> bar
> baz
> EOPerlInput
FOO
BAR
BAZ
```

You can even specify the heredoc before the command line arguments:

```
$ perl <<EOPerlInput -pe 's{(.*)}{\U$1}'
> foo
> bar
> baz
> EOPerlInput
FOO
BAR
BAZ
```

You can't do multiple heredocs, though:

```
$ perl <<EOPerlInput -pe 's{(.*)}{\U$1}' <<EOSecondInput
> foo
> bar
> baz
> EOPerlInput
> hello
> world
> EOSecondInput
HELLO
WORLD
```

unless you want to start using other file descriptors:

```
$ perl  -pe 's{(.*)}{\U$1}' /dev/fd/3 3<<EO3 /dev/fd/4 4<<EO4
> foo
> bar
> baz
> EO3
> hello
> world
> EO4
FOO
BAR
BAZ
HELLO
WORLD
```

Note that this last example is not using STDIN; it is using actual files:

```
$ perl  -pe 's{(.*)}{$ARGV: \U$1}' /dev/fd/3 3<<EO3 /dev/fd/4 4<<EO4
foo
bar
baz
EO3
hello
world
EO4
/dev/fd/3: FOO
/dev/fd/3: BAR
/dev/fd/3: BAZ
/dev/fd/4: HELLO
/dev/fd/4: WORLD
```

But the original example is using STDIN:

```
$ perl <<EOPerlInput -pe 's{(.*)}{$ARGV: \U$1}'
foo
bar
baz
EOPerlInput
-: FOO
-: BAR
-: BAZ
```

A pipe example:

```
$ (echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar; sleep 3; echo baz) | perl -pe '$now=time; s{(.*)}{$now: \U$1}'
1622995189: FOO
1622995194: BAR
1622995197: BAZ
```

You can use Bash's [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html), though:

```
$ perl -pe '$now=time; s{(.*)}{$now: \U$1}' <(echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar; sleep 3; echo baz)
1622995914: FOO
1622995919: BAR
1622995922: BAZ
```

Using a heredoc, the input is processed all at once, even if it takes a while to generate it:

```
$ perl -pe '$now=time; s{(.*)}{$now: \U$1}' <<EOF
> $(date +%s)
> $(sleep 5; date +%s)
> EOF
1623000458: 1623000453
1623000458: 1623000458
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? It's fully possible to run this (e.g., > ./averageCalculator <<EOF and then provide values for operations that the program performs. And the output is presented when you send "EOF" to the program.

Comment: "And the output is presented when you send "EOF" to the program." -- that's my point. I'll add an example.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and the examples! The issue I'm having is interpreting some requirements: The requirements essentially state: "Whenever a change is presented [...] the program should output this message back [...]"; hence, the example provided states "./program << EOF" and then the output looks like this "<timestamp> <message>, where it is supposed the program should report back the timestamp on each and every single message, before even EOF comes. What I believe is that this is not possible, until we reach EOF. Is this  true? If so I need to re-iterate the requirements.

Comment: It is not possible using a heredoc, to my knowledge. Added another example, though, using a pipe.

Comment: I think it's correct - I cannot see how to "push back" any type of message back until our program reaches EOF. I think it's a misinterpretation of the requirements (i.e., documentation fault). Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: I added an example using Bash's process substitution.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But this is given that you "send in" the actual time? What I'm after is whether the actual program - let's say a "timer" - could send this back using EOF? Let's say you have a program, that has some kind of internal timer - that on its own keeps track of the time. Would it then be possible to run this: "./program <<EOF" and send "now" to the program; and it responds with "12333...", on each single line? Isn't it the case the program responds to this until it receives EOF?

Comment: See latest example addition...even if there is time spent generating the input, it's still processed all at once.